# Transferring BNB from contract to Safe on Binance Smart Chain

Tags: gnosis-safe

In my contract I receive BNB from users and would like to transfer (withdraw) it to a gnosis safe address.

The function works with a normal address but does not seem to work with a "contract" address.

The following line of code breaks with "out of gas" when using a “contract” address

```
payable(profitAddress).transfer(profit);
```

- profitAddress: a gnosis safe address

And I follow those articles https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/5249851-why-can-t-i-transfer-eth-from-a-contract-into-a-safe, [Transferring ETH from contract to Safe](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/122347/transferring-eth-from-contract-to-safe), it still not work.

```js
const { ethers } = require('ethers')
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
require('dotenv').config()

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
  'https://rpc.tenderly.co/fork/6e26dd40-d373-4867-bbc4-892a45787425',
  {
    name: 'BSC',
    chainId: 56
  }
)

async function run() {
  let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, provider)
  wallet = wallet.connect(provider)
  const nft = new ethers.Contract(
    '0xBa9F0a830E89D4b8378d266da79BE32BD6c37458',
    ['function withdraw(address to) public'],
    wallet
  )
  const overrides = {
    gasLimit: 500000,
    gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('150', 'gwei').toString(),
    type: 1,
    accessList: [
      {
        address: '0xd5530Ea6d5832b9BACa571A66AB4051680645292', // admin gnosis safe proxy address
        storageKeys: [
          '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        ]
      },
      {
        address: '0x3E5c63644E683549055b9Be8653de26E0B4CD36E', // gnosis safe master address
        storageKeys: []
      },
      {
        address: '0xd9Db270c1B5E3Bd161E8c8503c55cEABeE709552', // gnosis safe master address
        storageKeys: []
      }
    ]
  }

  const tx = await nft.withdraw(
    '0x5A25944B3383Aab4f3B830d5D9f2Ba672D9fa9Ce',
    overrides
  )
  console.info({ tx })
  const resolved = await tx.wait()
  console.info({ resolved })
}

run()
```

- contract address: https://bscscan.com/address/0xBa9F0a830E89D4b8378d266da79BE32BD6c37458#code
- gnosis safe address: https://bscscan.com/address/0xd5530Ea6d5832b9BACa571A66AB4051680645292#code
- error message:
  [image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [Send ETH from a contract to a Gnosis Safe wallet on BSC/BNB](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/122461/send-eth-from-a-contract-to-a-gnosis-safe-wallet-on-bsc-bnb/122565#122565)

As mentioned there you can find a guide here: https://github.com/rmeissner/safe-migrator

Make sure to review all code in this guide, as the use is always at your own risk.

Note: BNB does not support the access list feature and does not plan to (see [Does bsc chain support eip2930?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/122558/does-bsc-chain-support-eip2930/122566#122566))

Answer (score 1):

The Solidity `.transfer` function transfers 2300 gas to the designated address. Apparently when the designated smart contract receives a transaction the smart contract uses more than 2300 gas . So you have to send more gas, this can be achieved with the Solidity [`.call`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=.call#address-related) function.